# Help in an integral equation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

When $f(x)$ is differentiable function satisfying
$$ x f(x)= x^2 + \int_0^x (x-t) f'(t) \,dt$$
find $f(1)$.

edited:
differentiating both sides get

$$ f(x) + x f'(x) = 2 x - x f'(0) $$
$$ f(x) = 2 x - x f'(x) - x f'(0) $$
putting $$ x = 1 $$
get
$$ f(1) = 2 - f'(1) - f'(0) $$
and stuck there. Any advice/link to topic would be appreciated

Comment: What have you done? Where are you stuck? Show your own work

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: If you want people doing your homework, you should give them a reason.

Comment: The derivative of the integral is wrong, I think, you should use [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let evaluate the integral part: $$\int_{0}^{x} (x-t)f'(t)dt$$ Using integration by part we get:
$$\int_{0}^{x} (x-t)f'(t)dt = [(x-t)f(t)]^x_0 - \int_{0}^{x} (x-t)'f(t)dt = -xf(0) -  \int_{0}^{x} (-f(t))dt = -xf(0) + \int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt $$

Thus: $$xf(x) = x^2 -xf(0) + \int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt$$
Differentiating both sides we get:
$$f(x) + xf'(x) = 2x - f(0) + f(x)$$
Hence: $$f'(x) = 2 - \frac{f(0)}{x}$$
Assume that $f(0) \neq 0$ ($f(0)$ exist since $f$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$)
 
Which give us: $f(x) = 2x - f(0)ln(x) + C$ for some real number $C$. 
 
 But this solution is not defined at $x = 0$, so our assumption was wrong and thus $f(0) = 0$ hence $f'(x) = 2$ and then $f(x) = 2x + C$ for some real number $C$.

 
Plugging this into the equation we get: $$2x^2 + Cx = x^2 + \int_{0}^{x} 2(x-t).dt = x^2 + 2[xt - \frac{1}{2}t^2]^x_0 = 2x^2$$ Thus $Cx = 0$ for all $x$, Hence $C = 0$
We conclude that $f(x) = 2x$ and by plugging 1 we get: $$f(1) = 2$$

Comment: Use double space to make larger spaces between lines, and also usee double dollar signs  at the beginning and end of formulas to get written in a separate, lcearer line. As you wrote it looks too dense, messy and not very clear.

Comment: @DonAntonio thank you

Comment: This is the correct answer. Mine has a mistake that I still have to find... +1

Comment: Keep going, you could notice the mistake if you go backward, starting from the solution and getting back to the problem